# Laravel: How to find if a user is logged in, without forcing a redirect?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've just discovered that the Auth facade will only work if the auth middleware is included. Unfortunately, including the auth middleware forces the user to redirect if they are not logged in. Which means that routes will either work only for logged in users, or only for non-logged-in users.

I want to have a single page, which can be visited regardless of whether the user is logged in or not, but which displays some additional data from the user object if they are. How do I do this?

It looks like the simplest method will be to create two routes, which are both backed by the same controller method. Is this the best way to do this?

Edit: 
With further investigation, I've discovered the problem is that the default guard is not the one the user logged in with, and I'm able to get the logged in user auth Auth::guard()->user() instead of Auth::user(). I can't change the default guard globally, so the question becomes: is there a way to set the default guard on a per-route basis? Or do I need to use auth::guard() everywhere?

Answer (score 6):

Use `Auth::check()` in your view to check if the user is logged in

Comment: Auth::check() returns false even if the user is logged in

Comment: then you are not logged in using the default laravel  user class

Comment: do you have a custom login implementation?

Comment: `Auth::check()` should return true / false

Comment: What do you get for `Auth::user()` when user is logged in?

Comment: Auth::check returns false and Auth::user returns null, unless I include the auth middleware - then check and user return values

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auth::check()

```
if($user = Auth::check())
{
    echo 'logged in';
}else{
    echo 'not logged in';
}
```

Comment: Auth::check returns false even if the user is logged in